# ng-class not working on a custom directive with templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, ng-class

I have a directive that calls a template. Within the template i am using ng-class which adds a class on click. However, on click, this class is not getting added.

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'home/user.html'
        }
    }
);
```

home/user.html

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="data.input[0].value" required ng-class="{true : 'necessary'}[errorFirstName]" id="firstname">
```

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <my-directive data="myData"></my-directive>

    <button ng-click="checkUsr()">Check user</button>
</div>
```

MyController.js

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkUsr = function() {
        $scope.errorFirstName = true;
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE:

I've tried compilign too:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'home/user.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: try scope: { data: "=data" }

Comment: This this..  ng-class="{neccessary : errorFirstName}"

Comment: You don't have myData defined in MyController and you're attempting to pass that as the data parameter to your directive. Try initializing a myData object in MyController: `$scope.myData = {errorFirstName: false};` and then altering your checkUsr function slightly: `$scope.myData.errorFirstName = true;`

Comment: @adamjld - tried your suggestion, it didnt work.

Comment: @JoshuaKelly - tried your suggestion, that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the only way i have been able to achieve the expected outcome is through:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkUsr = function() {
        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#username' ) );
        var angElement = angular.element(myEl);
        angElement.addClass('neccessary');
    }

});
```

This feels like a really old way of adding a class, and really not making use of ng-class at all.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Changed around your input..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-class="{neccessary : errorFirstName}" id="firstname" required />
```

Please take a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/65q63ux5/) and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: ng-model needs to remain as data.input[0].value as im binding this to an object retrieved on page load.

Comment: Yes, but with the provided information that you have given for this question, I am unable to interact with the text input while it's model is set to 'data.input[0].value'. So for a working Fiddle, it had to be changed :)